# Angular Translate - Update translations executed via $tranlate.instant() in controller at runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate, angular-controller

I am using angular-translate and trying to change languages at runtime (without refreshing the page) using a select menu (`on-change`). However, the front end of the application I'm working on gets its text from translations executed via the `$translate.instant()` method, and so when I execute the language change via `$translate.use(langKey);`, it has no effect on the text coming from within the controller.

It *does* work when the translations are executed via the HTML markup, using either a directive or a filter, but I am working on a relatively large existing codebase and trying to save myself the massive job of refactoring everything to move the translations into the markup.

<del>My controller code is below, and I've also set up a Plunker to demonstrate the issue (albeit with buttons instead of a dropdown, but the problem is the same): http://plnkr.co/edit/ohzN9G</del>

**UPDATE:** I did actually manage to get this working based on this solution: [angular translate update translation table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852190/angular-translate-update-translation-table). However, my version involves using a `$watch` for every controller, which is expensive in terms of performance, and would still require a decent amount of refactoring to implement across all controllers: http://plnkr.co/edit/TjEVeX

Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same result?

**JS**

```
var translationsEN = {
  HEADLINE: 'What an awesome module!',
  PARAGRAPH: 'Srsly!',
  PASSED_AS_TEXT: 'Hey there! I\'m passed as text value!',
  PASSED_AS_ATTRIBUTE: 'I\'m passed as attribute value, cool ha?',
  PASSED_AS_INTERPOLATION: 'Beginners! I\'m interpolated!',
  VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT: 'Hi {{name}}',
  MISSING_TRANSLATION: 'Oops! I have not been translated into German...',
  BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'German',
  BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'English'
};

var translationsDE= {
  HEADLINE: 'Was für ein großartiges Modul!',
  PARAGRAPH: 'Ernsthaft!',
  PASSED_AS_TEXT: 'Hey! Ich wurde als text übergeben!',
  PASSED_AS_ATTRIBUTE: 'Ich wurde als Attribut übergeben, cool oder?',
  PASSED_AS_INTERPOLATION: 'Anfänger! Ich bin interpoliert!',
  VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT: 'Hi {{name}}',
  // MISSING_TRANSLATION is ... missing :)
  BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'Deutsch',
  BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'Englisch'
};

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', ,'ngSanitize']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', 'translationHelperProvider', function ($translateProvider, translationHelperProvider) {
  // add translation tables
  $translateProvider.translations('en', translationsEN);
  $translateProvider.translations('de', translationsDE);
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
  $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
  $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');

  translationHelperProvider.translations = $translateProvider.translations();

}]);

app.provider('translationHelper', function () {
    this.translations = {};

    this.$get = function () {
        return {
            translations: this.translations,
            preferredLanguage: this.preferredLanguage
        }
    };  
});

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$translate', '$scope', 'translationHelper', function ($rootScope, $translate, $scope, translationHelper) {

  $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey).then(function () {
      $rootScope.globalLangKey = langKey;
    })

  }; 
}]);

app.controller('InnerCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$translate', '$scope', 'translationHelper', function ($rootScope, $translate, $scope, translationHelper) {
  $scope.translateMe = $translate.instant("HEADLINE");
 $rootScope.$watch('globalLangKey', function (newVal, oldVal) {
     if (newVal) {
       $scope.translateMe = translationHelper.translations[newVal]["HEADLINE"];
     }
 });
}]);

app.controller('AnotherInnerCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$translate', '$scope', 'translationHelper', function ($rootScope, $translate, $scope, translationHelper) {
  $scope.translateMeAParagraph = $translate.instant("PARAGRAPH");
 $rootScope.$watch('globalLangKey', function (newVal, oldVal) {
     if (newVal) {
       $scope.translateMeAParagraph = translationHelper.translations[newVal]["PARAGRAPH"];
     }
 });
}]);
```

**MARKUP**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js/v0.3.1/messageformat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.10.0/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/2.10.0/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-storage-cookie/2.10.0/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-storage-local/2.10.0/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-loader-url/2.10.0/angular-translate-loader-url.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-loader-static-files/2.10.0/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-handler-log/2.10.0/angular-translate-handler-log.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <p>{{ 'HEADLINE' | translate }}</p> 
  <p>{{ 'PARAGRAPH' | translate }}</p>


  <div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
    <hr>
    <h2>This is the new nested controller I set up as a test</h2>
    <br>
    I used code from within the controller to translate this: 
    <br> {{translateMe}}
    <br>
    <br>
    This was done using <pre style="display: inline; font-weight: bold">translate="PASSED_AS_ATTRIBUTE</pre> approach<br>
    <span translate="PASSED_AS_ATTRIBUTE"></span></pre> <span translate="PASSED_AS_ATTRIBUTE"></span>
    <hr>

  </div>

    <div ng-controller="AnotherInnerCtrl">
      Here is another nested controller with the translation being executed from within the controller: <p>{{translateMeAParagraph}}</p>
      <hr>
    </div>



  <button ng-click="changeLanguage('de')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_DE"></button>
  <button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_EN"></button>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use $translate.instant() , you should add $scope.$watch for the value that you are needed to trigger its code

Comment: You can that's what I've been doing if you look at my JS code - unless I'm misunderstsanding? Thanks, in any event!